# How is Xiaomi changing my browser home page?

Tags: web-browser, android, chrome

I have recently observed that the home page of Google Chrome on my Xiaomi Android phone has been altered to a website called "Mintnav". I did not update any software. How is Xiaomi able to change my home page and what else can they potentially do without my approval?

Comment: In practice, "your" Xiaomi Android also belongs to Google and Xiaomi.

Answer (score 42):

You are running an operating system customized by Xiaomi. An operating system is the execution environment for the application. It has higher privileges then the applications themselves and can do basically anything associated with the data on the device or the capabilities hardware - like spying on the users (or implement backdoors or "security issues" which allow others to do this), leaking user data, changing user data ...

This is not specific to Xiaomi and other vendors on Android - the same is true with Microsoft on Windows (which changes system behavior in order to [force users to use their own browser Edge](https://www.theverge.com/2023/5/3/23709297/microsoft-edge-force-outlook-teams-web-links-open)), Apple on iOS etc. And it is not restricted to more obvious digital devices like smartphones and notebooks, but is also true for SmartTV, modern cars ...

Of course, most buy devices by not assuming malicious behavior from the manufacturer or vendor of the digital device or operating system. But this is just hope and not in any way technically enforced. And unfortunately there is often a conflict of interest in what the users want (like full control over the device and privacy of their data) and what the vendor wants (making money).

In your specific case [reports indicate](https://www.mysmartprice.com/gear/xiaomi-users-allegedly-complain-of-mintnav-adware-in-browsers-heres-how-to-fix-it/) that this "making money" has led to Xiaomi partnering with Mintnav in order to profit from more advertisement sent to the user.

Comment: The only reasonable way to use a Xiaomi phone is with third-party OS ("ROM") like LineageOS (not great itself, poorly managed, but at least not malware) that doesn't have the vendor backdoors on it. Same kinda applies to most vendors, but it's worse when they're outside the regulatory jurisdiction that could in theory be protecting you from the worst vendor behaviors.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Not all Xiaomi phones have MIUI as stock firmware. There are Xiaomi Android One devices, for instance. LineageOS/cfw has the advantage of working on devices that are not receiving security updates any longer, the downside is that you need to unlock the bootloader, and thus many apps won't work unless you also root it.

Comment: Corporations have actually installed malicious software directly onto your computer, per the [Sony root-kit](https://fsfe.org/activities/drm/sony-rootkit-fiasco.en.html#:~:text=What%20Sony%20Did,included%20in%20Sony%20music%20CDs.) incident. So the fact that the company can directly modify the OS means that they can do even MORE behind your back.

Comment: @tomasz Xiaomi's last Android One device was released in 2019 with the last security update in 2022. It seems the trend has moved on to offer cheap Android Go (which can still contain a boatload of unremovable adware) for emerging markets and spec bragging devices for the rest.

Comment: @Nelson, this is something new for me, and it is a very interesting read. thanks for sharing. I wonder though with the more aggressive free stuff where user is the product, how many stuff are actually like this but no one knows or just stopped caring  / ended up in gray-ish kind of legal but actually not ethical.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE For the devices that are within regulatory jurisdiction, there are still stupid stuff that are extremely detrimental to you but are legal, such as sim locking. Branded phones can be straight-up locked once you cancel the plan and brick it, despite you "paying" for the phone.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE And which jurisdiction would that be? The main alternatives are under US jurisdiction and key difference to China is that the laws are publical so you know you are not protected from the worst vendor behavior and governmental spying. In China you don't know but can assume it is the same.

Comment: @quarague: I am not singling out any particular jurisdiction but pointing out that, if you buy a phone that was not designed for sale in the place where you live and whose maker is not governed by that place's laws, you're not going to have much recourse when they step all over you. Of course you don't have a lot even when it is the same jurisdiction, which I think it what I tried to say from the beginning. I don't think we're in disagreement.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Juristdiction or not, if OP is in the EU, their privacy laws also apply to foreign countries and thus this could be considered a breach of GDPR.

Comment: @SimaoGomesViana: Good luck suing a Chinese company who has no presence in the EU...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I'm not saying that you have success suing a Chinese company, but the fact that they can do this might as well show how little power the GDPR has outside the EU, and sometimes, even inside the EU.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to [Steffen's excellent answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/272105/284677), there's what is called an [Over-The-Air update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_update), that allows for updating your mobile phone (or any embedded system that is designed properly) at will, without your concent or *you even noticing* (e.g. [a/b updates](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/ab) for android).

Note that OTA updates can be done at [the firmware or at the operating system](https://www.techtarget.com/searchmobilecomputing/definition/OTA-update-over-the-air-update) level. Which means that they can do pretty much anything they want with your device without needing permissions.